# Why are there no binary literals in Java?

Tags: java

Is there any particular reason why this kind of literal is not included whereas hex and octal formats are allowed?

Comment: It is not included in most languages, maybe the same reason for it not being included in Java. But I would like to know the general reason anyway.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responses. In summary, I would say it is not included simply because C doesn't have it and not really because it adds complexity. Heck, octal is included and I don't see much use to it compared to binary but only because C has it. As we can see from this proposal http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000929.html , binary literals has lots of advantages especially in the bit oriented domain.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Java 7 includes it.Check the [new features](http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/).

**Example:**

```
int binary = 0b1001_1001;
```

Comment: Here's a more recent and more "official" reference - http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/

Comment: Great link +1. It lead me to this http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000929.html which sums up all my reasons why I would want to see a binary literal.

Comment: There's the more recent link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Answer (score 24):

Binary literals were introduced in Java 7. See ["Improved Integer Literals"](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_literal_grammar_hackery):

```
int i = 0b1001001;
```

The reason for not including them from day one is most likely the following: Java is a high-level language and has been quite restrictive when it comes to language constructs that are less important and low level. Java developers have had a general policy of "if in doubt, keep it out".

If you're on Java 6 or older, your best option is to do

```
int yourInteger = Integer.parseInt("100100101", 2);
```

Comment: C is mid-level language and has historically been quite permissive when it comes to language constructs that are very low level. Still, no binary literals.

Comment: Yes, that's IMO stranger. It has been present in GCC for quite a while though as I understand it.

Comment: How many people find octal literals more useful than they would find binary ones?

Answer (score 2):

actually, it is. in java7.

http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/

Answer (score 1):

The [associated bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5025288) is open since April 2004, has low priority and is considered as a request for enhancement by Sun/Oracle.

I guess they think binary literals would make the language more complex and doesn't provide obvious benefits...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an impression here that implementing binary literals is complex. It isn't. It would take about five minutes. Plus the test cases of course.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 does allow binary literals !
Check this:
int binVal = 0b11010;
at this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html