# Why is 09 "too large" of an integer number?

Tags: java

They think it is:

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

But if you check [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes) then you will find that the question is asked if before the launch of jdk7 and therefore it has lower researching efforts. But in jdk7 there is some change and addition to the integers. Here are the answers which are up to date covering jdk7.

I've a code:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x=09;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

On compilation it gives an error: integer number too large : 09

Why it do so?

Again, if I change the code to:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x=012;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Now the output is 10

Why it give the output 10 instead of 12?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Numbers beginning with `0` are considered [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) – and 9 is not an octal digit (but (conventionally) 0-7 are).

---

Hexadecimal literals begin with `0x`, e.g. `0xA`.

---

Up until Java 6, there was no literal notation for binary and
you'll had to use something like

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("1011011", 2);
```

where the second argument specifies the desired base.

---

Java 7 now has [binary literals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html).

> In Java SE 7, the integral types (byte, short, int, and long) can also be expressed using the binary number system. To specify a binary literal, add the prefix `0b` or `0B` to the number.

Comment: but what about the Binary and Hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: the thing left is Binary number. Number starting with 0 are octal, number starting with 0x are Hexadecimal, but is there any notation to represent Binary too?

Comment: @Mohammed Faisal: Java7 now has binary literals as well: `0b100100101` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013441/why-are-there-no-binary-literals-in-java

Comment: @Mohammad: Update my post - there are no binary decimals in Java (at least until version 6).

Answer (score 20):

Integer literals beginning with a "0" are treated as octal.  The permissible digits are 0 through 7.

Answer (score 14):

Integers beginning with the digit 0 are *octal* (base 8) numbers. The largest octal digit is 7; after 07 comes 010 (which is equal to decimal 8!)

012 (octal twelve) is 010 (octal ten, which is decimal 8) plus 2, or decimal 10.

Answer (score 8):

09 is an octal numeric literal, an invalid one though.

Hexadecimal numbers start with 0x, like 0xFFFF.

There used to be no binary literal in Java. Java 7 supports them, starting with 0b, like 0b00100001.

Comment: thank you! did previous versions on java like jdk6 does not support binary literals?

Comment: No they don't. you can do something like Integer.parseInt("1111111111", 2) for binaries;

Answer (score 6):

Numbers beginning with 0 are octal number.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal