# Get all sequences of 1 and 0

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to reach following sequences of 1 and 0 for a three input system:

```
000
001
010
...
...
```

My current code didn't make it :-

```
for (int i = 0; i < possibleCombinations; i++) {

        for (j = 0 ; j < 3; j++) {
            if (j < 2 ){
                k = j;
            }
            System.out.print(k + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

How i can reach above result?

Comment: down vote why ?

Comment: For such a small number of bits, bitmasks may be the best alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124165/declaring-masks-for-bitwise-operations (please note, I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: You need three for loops. I honestly can't tell what your for loops are trying to do to solve the problem, the first one is the length of possible combinations, the inner one is 3, so youll get three times the lines you need

Comment: @android, have a look to my answer. It requires only one iteration.

Comment: @Alexandru-ionut the complexity is still ``2^n`` though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bitmasks` for this:

```
 void generateCombinations(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
         for(int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if((i & (1 << j)) != 0) {
                System.out.print(1);
            } else {
                System.out.print(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So for `n = 3` you will have `2 ^ n = 8` combinations. That's why the first for is `1 << n`, this is the same as `2 ^ n`.
For every number you check whether it's bits and print them.

`(i & (1 << j)) != 0` - this checks if a bit is `1` or `0` on position `j`.

Comment: So I think you refer to the order of permutations, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One line:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   System.out.println(((i>>2)%2)+""+((i>>1)%2)+""+(i%2));
 }
```

You can generalize this for n-channels of course.

```
    int numChannels=3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2<<numChannels; i++) {
        for(int j=numChannels-1; j>=0;j--){
            System.out.print((i>>j)%2);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Think it about using the periodicity of the occurence of zeroes and ones (first channel has pattern 00001111.., second 0011.., third 01..).

Answer (score 0):

We have these situations:

`n=2;` -> `00,01,10,11`

`n=3;`->`000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111.`

....

The **algorithm** is to just enumerate all numbers till `2^n - 1` in binary. For instance , `n=2` :

`0` in binary will be `00`

`1` in binary will be `01`

`2` in binary will be `10`

`3` in binary will be `11`

For converting one **integer** number to **binary string**, you should use `Integer.toBinaryString` method.

Code:

```
 static String print_binary(int n)
 {
    String binaryString=Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    String additional=new String(new char[n-binaryString.length()]).replace("\0", "0");
    if(binaryString.length() < n)
            binaryString+=additional;
    return binaryString;
 }
 static void Main(String args[]){
     int possibleCombinations = 1<<LENGTH, i; 
     for(i = 0; i< possibleCombinations; i++)
         System.out.println(print_binary(i));
 }
```

Comment: Not really the good solution, missing leading zeroes  if you use just Integer.toBinaryString  without additional formatting ;)