# expected ; error when initializing an int variable with binary value in java

Tags: java, binary, osx-yosemite

Below is the code:

```
class PlayWithBinary {
    static int age;

    public static void main (String args[]){
        int i = 0b10101010;
        System.out.println("my age is: " + age + " my salary is: "+ i);
    }
}
```

In terminal I executed : `javac PlayWithBinary.java`

For some reasons it is showing this error message:

```
PlayWithBinary.java:5: ';' expected
        int i = 0b10101010;
                 ^
1 error
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** for those who are getting similar errors, here is the link to download JDK 8 - [Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Binary literals were introduced with Java 7.

Comment: Code  works fine for Java >= 7

Comment: Use JDK 7 or 8 as of now to get this code working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your project is configured with a Java compliance level of Java 7 or above, or you could modify your code to use [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) like

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("10101010", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using an older version of Java that doesn't support this. This feature was added in Java 7 - see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013441/why-are-there-no-binary-literals-in-java). You should upgrade your Java version to fix this.

Alternatively, you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) on your code: `int i = Integer.parseInt("10101010", 2);`